# Best Solution for a Printer Specifically for Visitors

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers, printer, network-printer, cabling

In our conference room there isn't much space for cabling all we have is easy access to ethernet ports. The HP printer is not wireless. 
I was wondering what the best discrete solution would be other than a very long usb cable and manually installing print drivers to a person's laptop.
Our wireless connection does not connect to our network we keep it seperate for obvious reasons. Therefore they cannot connect to our network printers. Are there any cheap hardware solutions or am I stuck hiding a usb cable to the center of the confeence room and using a driver cd or thumbdrive to install the drivers?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind an inkjet, I would probably just go with a HP printer that has ePrint - this would allow your guests to send their document in an e-mail to the printers unique e-mail address without needing to physically connect to the printer or install drivers.

[Linksys print server (refub)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0012BP0A6)  - make your current printer wireless for $50 but need drivers 
[HP e-Print enabled printer](http://www.officedepot.com/a/products/691557/HP-Photosmart-Plus-ePrint-All-In/?cm_mmc=Mercent-_-Google-_-Printers_Scanners_Copiers_Faxes-_-691557&mr:trackingCode=D68F4961-B5C1-DF11-98FF-0019B9C043EB&mr:referralID=NA) - New printer for $100 (no drivers, no usb cable)

Answer (score 1):

If you can spare an old laptop or PC (with wireless), then you can connect the printer to that using USB cable. Then connect the PC/laptop to your guest wireless network and share the printer queue.

Your guest users can connect to the PC via network and double-click on the shared queue to automatically install the driver and print.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I would just bite the bullet and get a wireless printer. It sounds like this would solve most of your problems. Also with a lot of people using tablets now you might want to get one that supports native printing from the tablet. For minimal use I like the http://www.shopping.hp.com/webapp/shopping/product_detail.do?storeName=storefronts&landing=printer&category=ENVY&lanAttr=Brand&product_code=CN517A%23B1H&catLevel=2 of course depending on usage needs your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the USB printer to wireless with an adapter such as [this](http://homesupport.cisco.com/en-us/support/printservers/WPSM54G).  The guests could then map directly to the printer.  You might have to get a wireless router, too.  But thats a small investment. And the router doesnt have to be connected to the internet or your network to keep it secure.